# Suggest banning Church tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Suggest banning [church](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church) as a tag, since the word *"church"* is used for two separate purposes in the New Testament. So, instead of *"church"*, how about:

- [global-church](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/global-church) see [Matthew 16:18](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2016:18&version=NIV):

  > And I tell you that you are Peter, and on this rock I will build my **church**, and the gates of Hades will not overcome it.
- [local-church](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/local-church) see [Matthew 18:17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2018:17&version=NIV):

  > If they still refuse to listen, tell it to the **church**; and if they refuse to listen even to the **church**, treat them as you would a pagan or a tax collector.

In this way it is always clear which of the two distinct meanings is meant.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, but I don't think that's a good solution. The terms aren't going to be well-enough understood by questioners to use them correctly. But there might be better names.

Comment: @DJClayworth - yeah, I'm not completely happy with banning such a well known word as "church". I'm open to better suggestions.

Comment: I'd be interested in a rough survey of how many questions use the tag in each sense; and how many use it without distinguishing between the two.

Comment: You should post your suggestion as an answer rather than include it in the question. That way we can vote on your question and suggestion seperately

Comment: I haven't fully thought through my answer yet.

Comment: For information I looked at the church tag: it has 12 questions. 9 are clearly about local churches or denomination; 2 are about the church-universal (one is about both); one is specifically about denominations and one is about church buildings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest removing the 'church' tag and replacing it with three tags:

- church-universal
- church-local
- church-building

I suggest 'church-universal' and 'church-local' rather than 'universal-church' and 'local-church' so that they come up as suggestions when the questioner starts to type 'church'. I prefer 'church-universal' to 'church-global' because I think it's a more frequently understood term. Programmers will understand the difference between global and local, but most people won't.

Comment: Love it. Smart thinking.

Comment: I've started putting this into practice by creating those tags.

Answer (score -3):

Just to add something else which shouldn't be forgotten:

- [church-militant](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-militant) folks just trying to make it through the day
- [church-suffering](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-suffering) the holy souls in purgatory
- [church-triumphant](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-triumphant) guys and gals who made it to heaven.

Comment: we might also want to consider banning [tag:church-turing-thesis]

Comment: I think those concepts/terms (which I know and use but with the second two having entirely different scopes ;) should be reserved for answers with explanations. I don't expect them to scope site questions for visitors. If you see questions that could benefit from such a breakdown feel free to propose them again then.

Comment: Can we also ban church-charlotte?

Comment: @djc, I think she banned herself

Comment: @PeterTurner: Touché